# How do I change frequency of telemetry of Azure IoT Edge simulated tempSensor module

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I would like to change the frequency of the simulated tempSensor module so that it sends telemetry to the IoT Hub every 60 seconds, not every 5 seconds. I cannot find the code in order to create my own C# module or to modify the one that Azure has as a sample. How do I change the frequency of the telemetry of this simulated temperature sensor module used in the IoT Edge walkthrough?

https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor/

I have an Azure Iot Hub with 8000 messages per day and Iot Edge device simulated and a tempSensor and filterModule through Docker setup etc... All is working well.

I could write another C# module similar to the filterModule which would function like a time filter and averages 12 readings together and sends a message every 60 seconds and then the filterModule does it's job after.  So the route would go from tempSensor to timeFilter to filterModule. Along this line of thinking.

**SIMULATED TEMPERATURE SENSOR in Docker**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/?service=iot-hub&sort=0&term=simulated

Where do I find the code for that example? I looked here:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples

I am trying to learn how the simulated temperature sensor module works in the code in order to build off that to create my own IoT modules.

I found something close but am not sure how to go between this code and the modules used in IoT Edge.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/iot?view=azure-dotnet

I don't see API reference here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/

Here are some other places I looked:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-edge

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-toolkit

Answer (score 2):

The source code is not currently open source.

### Update:

Currently (April 2018) the code is open-sourced under the MIT licence and can be found on GitHub here:[link](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/tree/master/v2/samples/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor)

To solve your immediate need, there is an undocumented setting for adjusting the delay. All the available settings for the Simulated Temperature sensor module (and default values):

> "MessageDelay": "00:00:05",
>
> "machineTempMin": 21,
>
> "machineTempMax": 100,
>
> "machinePressureMin": 1,
>
> "machinePressureMax": 10,
>
> "ambientTemp": 21,
>
> "ambientHumidity": 25

This may be set as environment variables in the "createOptions" section, like this:

```
      "tempSensor": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "type": "docker",
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always",
        "settings": {
          "image": "microsoft/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor:1.0-preview",
          "createOptions": "{\"Env\":[\"MessageDelay=00:01:00\"]}"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful information. SInce I had already created the module I used the "Set Module" method to modify the tempSensor and in the "Container Create Options" section I placed the following line: {
  "Env":["MessageDelay=00:01:00"]
}

Comment: One more comment or question: Is the code sample provided for a C# filterModule similar in any way to a simulated module such as the tempSensor? I would like to write code to study my own simulated modules and am not sure where an example is. I was thinking this tempSensor example would have code to study but I see it is not yet open source. Where to find sample code for simulating sensors for use in an Iot Edge scenario?

Comment: You can use Visual Studio Code to develop a C# module with Azure IoT Edge,please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vscode-develop-csharp-module

Comment: Actually the code is posted here with the MIT license. https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/tree/master/v2/samples/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor  - could be this was posted right around your answer though.

Comment: i'm trying to replace simulated temp image with my own python one, which sends telemetry to IOT Central... is there any python version to simulated temp sensor sample?.